# HMAC SHA256 - Convert Server Side Ruby Code to Client Side Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, ruby, cryptography, sha256, hmac

I would like to convert my existing Ruby function, which runs on a server, into Javascript code, which will run in the client browser.

The function creates a SHA256 signature by importing an array of parameters and a key.

**Here is the Ruby function:**

```
def params_with_signature(params, secret)
  params = params.reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }
  query_string = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), secret, query_string)
  params = params.merge(signature: signature)
end
```

**Here is the data being passed through the Ruby Function:**

```
secret = 'abcdef'

params = {
  one: 'a',
  two: 'b',
  three: 'c'
}

puts params_with_signature(params, secret)
```

I've made some progress using standard sha256 (without HMAC) with the Forge project:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@0.7.0/dist/forge.min.js'></script>
<script>
  var string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
  var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
  md.update(string);
  hashed_string = (md.digest().toHex());
  console.log(hashed_string)
</script>
```

It does appear that they have an HMAC module, but I'm not familiar with Javascript enough to implement (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#hmac).

The bottom line here is that I would like all of this to run on the client device. I would prefer not to do this with node.js because I know that also runs on a server.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a question. Try yourself and possibly post when you get stuck.